# Can't fit data to 3d convolutional U-net Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution, semantic-segmentation

I have a problem. I want to make 3D convolutional U-net. For this purpose I'm using Keras.

My data are MRI images from [Data Science Bowl 2017 Competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/data-science-bowl-2017/data). All MRI's were saved in numpy arrays (all pixels are scaled from 0 to 1) with shape:

```
data_ch.shape
(94, 50, 50, 50, 1)
```

94 - patients, 50 MRI slices of 50x50 images, 1 channel:
[image: The patients MRI from dataset]

I want to make 3D Convolutional U-net, so the inputs and outputs of this net are same 3d arrays.
The 3D U-net:

```
input_img= Input(shape=(data_ch.shape[1], data_ch.shape[2], data_ch.shape[3], data_ch.shape[4]))
x=Conv3D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x=MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x=Conv3D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x=MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x=UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2))(x)
x=Conv3D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x) # PADDING IS NOT THE SAME!!!!!
x=UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2))(x)
x=Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='sigmoid')(x)

model=Model(input_img, x)
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

model.summary()
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         (None, 50, 50, 50, 1)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_27 (Conv3D)           (None, 50, 50, 50, 8)     224       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_12 (MaxPooling (None, 25, 25, 25, 8)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_28 (Conv3D)           (None, 25, 25, 25, 8)     1736      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling3d_13 (MaxPooling (None, 13, 13, 13, 8)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling3d_12 (UpSampling (None, 26, 26, 26, 8)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_29 (Conv3D)           (None, 26, 26, 26, 8)     1736      
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling3d_13 (UpSampling (None, 52, 52, 52, 8)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_30 (Conv3D)           (None, 50, 50, 50, 1)     217       
=================================================================
Total params: 3,913
Trainable params: 3,913
Non-trainable params: 0
```

But, when I attempted to fit data to this net:

```
model.fit(data_ch, data_ch, epochs=1, batch_size=10, shuffle=True, verbose=1)
```

the program displayed an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Taranov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    883             outputs =\
--> 884                 self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
    885                 self.fn(output_subset=output_subset)

ValueError: CudaNdarray_CopyFromCudaNdarray: need same dimensions for dim 1, destination=13, source=14

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-b334d38d9608> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(data_ch, data_ch, epochs=1, batch_size=10, shuffle=True, verbose=1)

C:\Users\Taranov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
   1496                               val_f=val_f, val_ins=val_ins, shuffle=shuffle,
   1497                               callback_metrics=callback_metrics,
-> 1498                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1499 
   1500     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1, sample_weight=None):

C:\Users\Taranov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch)
   1150                 batch_logs['size'] = len(batch_ids)
   1151                 callbacks.on_batch_begin(batch_index, batch_logs)
-> 1152                 outs = f(ins_batch)
   1153                 if not isinstance(outs, list):
   1154                     outs = [outs]

C:\Users\Taranov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   1156     def __call__(self, inputs):
   1157         assert isinstance(inputs, (list, tuple))
-> 1158         return self.function(*inputs)
   1159 
   1160 

C:\Users\Taranov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    896                     node=self.fn.nodes[self.fn.position_of_error],
    897                     thunk=thunk,
--> 898                     storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
    899             else:
    900                 # old-style linkers raise their own exceptions

C:\Users\Taranov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py in raise_with_op(node, thunk, exc_info, storage_map)
    323         # extra long error message in that case.
    324         pass
--> 325     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
    326 
    327 

C:\Users\Taranov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    683             value = tp()
    684         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    686         raise value
    687 

C:\Users\Taranov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    882         try:
    883             outputs =\
--> 884                 self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
    885                 self.fn(output_subset=output_subset)
    886         except Exception:

ValueError: CudaNdarray_CopyFromCudaNdarray: need same dimensions for dim 1, destination=13, source=14
Apply node that caused the error: GpuAlloc(GpuDimShuffle{0,2,x,3,4,1}.0, Shape_i{0}.0, TensorConstant{13}, TensorConstant{2}, TensorConstant{13}, TensorConstant{13}, TensorConstant{8})
Toposort index: 163
Inputs types: [CudaNdarrayType(float32, (False, False, True, False, False, False)), TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(int8, scalar), TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(int64, scalar)]
Inputs shapes: [(10, 14, 1, 14, 14, 8), (), (), (), (), (), ()]
Inputs strides: [(21952, 196, 0, 14, 1, 2744), (), (), (), (), (), ()]
Inputs values: ['not shown', array(10, dtype=int64), array(13, dtype=int64), array(2, dtype=int8), array(13, dtype=int64), array(13, dtype=int64), array(8, dtype=int64)]
Outputs clients: [[GpuReshape{5}(GpuAlloc.0, MakeVector{dtype='int64'}.0)]]

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

I tried to follow recommendations and use theano flags:

```
import theano
import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32, optimizer='None',exception_verbosity=high"
```

But it still doesn't work.

Could you help me?
Many thanks!

Comment: The problem is not in the code you posted. How are you calling the "fit" method? And what are the shapes of all the arrays you're passing to that method?

Comment: I've edited my question form. I used model.fit(data_ch, data_ch, epochs=1, batch_size=10, shuffle=True, verbose=1). The shape of arrays - (94, 50, 50, 50, 1). 94 patients, 50 slioces, 50x50 pixels, 1 channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.... that sounds weird, but `MaxPooling3D` has some kind of bug with `padding='same'`. So I wrote your code without it, and added an initial padding just to make your dimensions compatible:

```
import keras.backend as K

inputShape = (data_ch.shape[1], data_ch.shape[2], data_ch.shape[3], data_ch.shape[4])
paddedShape = (data_ch.shape[1]+2, data_ch.shape[2]+2, data_ch.shape[3]+2, data_ch.shape[4])

#initial padding
input_img= Input(shape=inputShape)
x = Lambda(lambda x: K.spatial_3d_padding(x, padding=((1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1))),
    output_shape=paddedShape)(input_img) #Lambda layers require output_shape

#your original code without padding for MaxPooling layers (replace input_img with x)
x=Conv3D(filters=8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x=MaxPooling3D(pool_size=2)(x)
x=Conv3D(filters=8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x=MaxPooling3D(pool_size=2)(x)

x=UpSampling3D(size=2)(x)
x=Conv3D(filters=8, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x) # PADDING IS NOT THE SAME!!!!!
x=UpSampling3D(size=2)(x)
x=Conv3D(filters=1, kernel_size=3, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model=Model(input_img, x)
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.summary()
print(model.predict(data_ch)[1])
model.fit(data_ch,data_ch,epochs=1,verbose=2,batch_size=10)
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!!! Did I understand you correctly that this error is only related to padding='same' ?

Comment: Yes, it's only related to `padding='same'` in MaxPooling layers. (In theory, we simply shouldn't use it, I think...). It's meant to be used in Convolutional layers.

Comment: Daniel, I'm sorry, one more question. Could you explain, what does K.spatial_3d_padding? I can't understand it ((( Is it the same as padding='same' in pooling?

Comment: Why after the Lambda function we use kernel_size=3, but not the kernel_size=(3, 3, 3)?

Comment: The `spacial_3d_padding` is adding a border with zeros. Instead of starting with a 50x50x50 volume, you will start with a 52x52x52 volume. This will guarantee that after the last pooling, you have 13x13x13 instead of 12x12x12. It was just a way to make the dimensions match at the end. (Since you apply 2 poolings, you need a starting number that is a multiple of 4 in order to be able to come back to the same number with upsamplings).

Comment: Using `kernel_size=3` is the same as using `kernel_size=(3,3,3)`. I was testing around and ended up leaving it this way. You only need to define the entire tuple if you want each dimension to have a different size.

Comment: Many thanks again! Now everything is clear. The model is training perfectly, but slowly))

Comment: The only thing I could think to make it faster (I don't know if significantly), is to duplicate data_ch, doing the "pad" in the data itself and removing the Lambda layer. (padded_data_ch with 52 size, and data_ch with 50 size).

Comment: Hm, interesting! Maybe we can better change the architecture of model to achieve the 50 size on output?)

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the batch size to something like 2, and if you see, your network needs more GPU, So try upgrading that as well.